# Mac ssh terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

So I am on an old (fully aluminum) macbook pro running snow leopard and using terminal to ssh into remote hosts on my work network. I am noticing a strange thing when I copy and paste things in the terminal.

For example I will grep for something like this in a file:

```
samtools view sorted-616.bam | grep 'SOLEXA9:1:1:30:3316:10211' | head -n 1
```

and it gives

SOLEXA9:1:1:30:3316:10211   69  k26_179705  159 0   *   =   159 0   TATGCCGCCAAACGCTTCCGCAAAGCTCTGTGTTTGACTATGTAGCGACTA CBCCCCCC@CCCCCCCCC?@CC?CC########################## RG:Z:1

But now when I select it, hit command+c to copy, and then command+v to paste, it comes out like this:

SOLEXA9:1:1:30:3316:1021169k26_1797051590*=1590TATGCCGCCAAACGCTTCCGCAAAGCTCTGTGTTTGACTATGTAGCGACTACBCCCCCC@CCCCCCCCC?@CC?CC##########################RG:Z:1

Notice how there are no spaces in between fields now. Is there a special method to copy and paste things exactly as they are?? Why is terminal behaving this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you use pbcopy?

```
samtools view sorted-616.bam | grep 'SOLEXA9:1:1:30:3316:10211' | head -n 1 | pbcopy
```

This should do the same thing that the copy command does, but without having to select the output you want.

Have you tried another terminal emulator? I use [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) because it will copy to the clipboard on selection without having to hit Command-c.

**EDIT:** You may have to install Apple's developer tools to get the pbcopy/pbpaste tools.

Comment: iTerm2 works great, I think I'll just switch over to that. Thanks for the suggestion! Was too lazy to install Apple developer tools ugh, need to pay for them too.

Comment: Xcode and the tools are free to download for anybody with an Apple ID. If you are running Lion (10.7) you can install Xcode from the Mac App Store. The command line tools are available at <https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action>. An Apple ID is required to log in, but that is also free if you don't already have one. Older version of Xcode3 are available at that same URL.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why the spaces are missing from the pasted text, but I'd try to write the output to a file, open up the file in an editor and try to see if it's something other than the standard space/newline characters. You seem to know your way with piping, but anyway:

```
samtools view sorted-616.bam | grep 'SOLEXA9:1:1:30:3316:10211' | head -n 1 > file.txt
```

It might depend on which system the host is running. I have had some issues while on ssh connections to linux/unix hosts, while Mac-to-Mac usually works just fine.

Comment: This happens when I copy and paste to anything on terminal, even into vim. Unfortunately I am aware that I could just pipe it into a file, but thats not what I want, that would involve 'grep'ing for something in a 50gig file and waiting for the command to finish to get one line in. I would rather just 'head -n 30' it and copy a few lines manually using vim. So while this does offer a somewhat viable workaround, it does not solve the problem.

But +1'd for trying :).